# NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName crash in swift and object-c, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash, nsnotificationcenter

I use a c library with object-c, and call the object-c in swift. here is the code:
 1. in HomeViewController.swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector(), name: "doAddEffectsFinished", object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "doAddEffectsFinished", object: nil);
    }
```

In the Fmodwrapper.mm file,

```
-(void) doAddEffects
{
    inpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"modulator22"
                                              ofType: @"wav"] UTF8String];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"doAddEffectsFinished" object:nil];
}
```

In the HomeViewController.swift, I use the code like this:

```
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
                    fmodWrapper.addEffects(0)   
        }
    }
```

when i run the code, it will crashed in the fmodwrapper.mm, at the line

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"doAddEffectsFinished" object:nil];
```

and I add below code in fmodwrapper.mm, but it not work

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

please help me, my friends, thank you.

Comment: It would be easier if you posted the error. Why do you have "Selector()" instead of the function name?

Comment: What's your handler for the notification? Where you define `Selector()` it should be an actual method on that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my fault , just change the Selector() to Selector("doAddEffectsFinished")